# Can't ping on wifi can ping on ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ping

I have a raspberry pi running Arch Linux on my home network.
It is connected via a cable to my home router, but I recently added a wi-fi dongle to it.

The funny thing is I can not ping anything (router or my laptop) via the wlan0 interface - No response comes back.

I can however ping both router and laptop via eth0 from the raspberry
and I can ping the raspberry on both interfaces from my laptop.
I also am able to pull my router's welcome page with curl using the wlan0 interface.

What am I missing?

Comment: Think about it, what happens when you pull the ethernet cable?

Comment: Is a dns service running on the Rpi OR the router ? if on the router is Rpi set to grab such from the router?

Comment: @ linuxdev2013 I think the DNS service is running on the router, but I don't get why DNS would matter if I am pinging by IP, not by hostname. 

@LotPings Sorry - I dont fully understand. What does it mean "pull the ethernet cable"?

Comment: Actually the problem kind of resolved on its own. I am able to ping when I specify interface's IP, but not when I specify "wlan0", Despite the fact that specifying "eth0" in its place works fine.